# Slick Slide slickAdd returns false

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

Im trying to add a slide to an empty slick slider that has been initialized.  I am using the statement:

```
$('.mapOfficeSlideshow.slick-slider').slick('slickAdd', '<div><h3>test</h3></div>', 0, false);
```

When i do the statement it returns false.  Addintionally, if i just try adding it without specifying the atIndex and the addBefore nothing gets added:

```
$('.mapOfficeSlideshow.slick-slider').slick('slickAdd', '<div><h3>test</h3></div>');
```

This is my initiate code below:

```
function initiateSlider() {
        console.log("start");
        var $mapOfficeSlideshow = $('.mapOfficeSlideshow.slick-slider');
        if ($mapOfficeSlideshow.length) {

            // Initialize slick
            $mapOfficeSlideshow.slick({
                slide: '.slide',
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 7000,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                dots: true,
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                rows: 0,
                prevArrow: $('.mapOfficeSlideshow .prev'),
                nextArrow: $('.mapOfficeSlideshow .next')
            });
        }
        console.log("end");

    }
```

Its worth noting that if i add the manually before initiating the slider itself works fine.  Its just adding slides that doesn't work.  Additionally, removing slides works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This works fine for me:

```js
$('.mapOfficeSlideshow.slick-slider').slick('slickAdd', '<div><h3>test</h3></div>', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

So one thing i did wrong was i didn't add the proper classes to the slide i wanted to add.  it would have "slide lazy" as a class in my case.
Additionally, it appears that adding slides to the slider if it didn't have any when initiated was causing problems.  once it had some i could remove and add freely.